# How to insert a formula at the end of a column that change monthly in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

```
Name    Description Jan Feb Mar total   Averga
lalo    the boy     12  123 121 256     ?
```

I have this Columns, but at the end, after column "total" I want to insert a formula, but this report execute monthly, How can I program to do this task automatically
?
Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?... did you try to use macrorecorder to do so?

Comment: also, explain what you mean by "this report execute monthly". How? By whom? Can't you just add the formula as part of the monthly run?

Comment: This info I copy from a Pivot Table.

Comment: I want to enter after the column "total" an Average of the quantity in the months, but the problem is that the months could be: "Jan, Jun, Dic" or " Jul, May, Dic" ( in other word could be 3 or 2 or 4 months).

Answer (score 0):

Short of the code, it seems what you need to know is how to determine how many columns are relevant. [=MATCH](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php) with searching for "Total" in your labels rows should find the column number containing `256` in your example and much the same searching for "Description" the column number containing `the boy`. Subtract the former from the latter and deduct one for the quantity of 'month' columns.